# mPDF CSS class for text color of <i> nested in <li> overridden by parent's color

Tags: mpdf

relevant HTML looks like:

```
    <li class="lineEntry t1" title="Right-Click for Options" style="">
     <span id="job_111095">
        <i class="ic-p-appr"></i> 111095
     </span> Foo/Bar, Some Text </span>
    </li>
```

... and the relevant CSS looks like ( file = icomoon's foo.css ) ...

```
/* this is an icomoon icon, that should be green */
.ic-p-appr:before { 
  content: "\e905";
  color: #0f8040 !important;
}
```

... and ( file = bar.css ) ...

```
    .t1{color:#B92426;}
    /* .line-entry never defines a color */
```

I have added !important AND loaded the foo.css After the bar.css in an effort to make the icon green (#0f8040), but the icon nested within the .t1 class always inherits that parent's font color ONLY when mpfd converts the HTML to a pdf doc.  (the nested icon in HTML works as expect)

When I look at the mPDF documentation for supported CSS, I see nothing there or in SO that suggests why this occurs.  My mPDF is 7, and here is the configuration:

```
    $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
        'fontDir' => array_merge($fontDirs, [
            '../vendor/resources/fonts',
        ]),
        'fontdata' => $fontData + [
            'icomoon' => [
                'R' => 'icomoon.ttf',
            ],
        ],
        'format' => 'A4-L',
        'orientation' => 'L',
        'debug' => true,
    ]);
```

see: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiMuw.png)
Help with this issue is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed: I discovered that because mPDF ver7 does not support CSS pseudo class :before, it was necessary to declare the font-color independently with the class name.  So for my HTML output, this worked, .ic-p-appr:before {  color: #0f8040 !important; } but I had to declare it again, minus the ':before' to register that style in the PDF document.

Summary: mPDF7 ignores CSS style attributes declared under a pseudo-class.